# Split string to only get positions 1, 2 and 3, removing everything else

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, json

I am using nodejs + mysql, and I want to show a date in a json api.

The date is not a string, is a mysql date type.

E* I can't select date(columnname) because I am already selecting everything from the table. This is my query:

```
var query_ = `
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ss.name) AS technologies 
FROM Projects_Project AS p
JOIN Projects_rel_Project_Skill AS prps ON prps.Project = p.ProjectID
JOIN Skills AS ss ON ss.skillID = prps.Skill
GROUP BY p.ProjectID
ORDER BY p.date DESC;`;
```

```
var mylist = results.map(row => ({
    'date': row.date
}));
```

This will output:
"2022-08-24T05:00:00.000Z"

So my attempt was to use .split after the T, but it gives an error saying that .split can only be used to strings and date is not a string.

```
var mylist = results.map(row => ({
    'date': row.date.split('T')[0]
}));
```

So searching more I attempt to convert it to string, but the output is different.

```
var mylist = results.map(row => ({
    'date': row.date.toString()
}));
```

"Wed Aug 24 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"

So now the problem is that I only want "Aug 24 2022" and I don't know how to do it. Using `.split(' ')[1]` will only give me "Aug"

I also attempt to do `.split(' ')[1, 2, 3]` and `.split(' ')[1][2][3]` but nothing.

Comment: if you just want the date, instead of selecting yourdatetimecolumn, select `date(yourdatetimecolumn)`

Comment: I can't, I will edit the post to show why. I read about that online, but I am selecting * from the table in mysql

Comment: If `row.date` is an instance of `Date` use `row.date.toISOString()`and then `split("T")` or use `toLocaleString()` with appropriate options

Comment: selecting * is always a bad idea, you should only select the columns or expressions you actually want.

Comment: I do it like that because I am using a for loop to get what I need from the query. `for (let key in results){` and `if(lastPushedId !== results[key].categoryId){` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `toLocaleDateString` to format the date. For example:

```js
date: row.date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  year: 'numeric'
});
```

This would output `Aug 24, 2022`.

See here for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 1):

you need to [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) your  splitted date

```
wantedDate = .split(' ').slice(1, 3)
```

then you can join your wantedDate to get the string date

Answer (score 1):

`row.date` is a `Date` object, you can convert it into string with `toISOString()` method:

```js
const now = new Date();
console.log(now.toISOString().split("T"))
```

So in your case it would be:

```
var mylist = results.map(row => ({
    'date': row.date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
}));
```